# How can I block a country from accessing my website on Amazon Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have a website that is only for US customer and I noticed on my analytic that I have been getting a lot of traffic from Russia. That is probably bots or spammers.

I'm using amazon route 53 for my DNS is it possible to create a rule using their GEO DNS to block these traffics?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Route 53 details page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html):

> When you use geolocation routing, you can localize your content and
>   present some or all of your website in the language of your users. You
>   can also use geolocation routing to restrict distribution of content
>   to only the locations in which you have distribution rights.

So it certainly sounds possible. If you are using [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) you could also setup [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/) rules to block the traffic. If you are using [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) as your CDN you can very easily select countries you want to block.

Answer (score 0):

Recently released [Traffic Flow](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/traffic-flow.html) allows one to easily create a traffic policy with a Geo rule and only include US location, like in the example below.

[image]

Comment: can you do 'not' locations? (the editor fails for me, so I can't check)

Comment: If you don't provide a "Default" as another location (first option in a list) - unmatched locations will be rejected. As for failing editor - we're only aware of certain browsers beta versions where it might malfunction. It works in IE 9+ and recently released versions of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. Could you drop me a line to goldin[at]amazon.com about how do you see it fails?